# AttributeError: can't set attribute in appium-python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, appium

```
import time
import unittest
from appium.webdriver.webdriver import WebDriver as AppiumDriver
from appium import webdriver
desired_caps = dict(
platformName='Android',
deviceName='Android Emulator',
app=('C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/h.a/asan.apk')
)
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

i recieved this error: appium-python

i got this message:

how can i fix it?

am using appium and android studio emulator to simulate and automation test of android application.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\workspace\top web\complete.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 229, in start_session
    self.capabilities = response.get('value')
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it got fixed by re-installing appium with python instead of npm.

I installed appium from source https://github.com/appium/python-client

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just updated "Appium-Python-Client" package to latest version. It is a python package.